# php xcrud column not display full text

Tags: php

I use xcrud for display database table in admin dashboard.

My problem is in **frontend table one column not display full text** like database.How I fixed?

Front Table column width cannot movable.

***Database view***
[image: database view]

***Frontend view***

[image]

**Update**

After add `$xcrud->column_width('account_type', '100%');` only column width increase,but problem in same.

[image]

Comment: try with `column_width` . e.g. `$xcrud->column_width('description','65%');`.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave I try this with putting column width 100%,But problem not solve only width of column increase.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave nothing change. Stlil same.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave no not yet :(

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave yes I'm waiting for working answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In xcrud, `column_width` refers to the width in pixels of a given column. What you are looking for is the `column_cut` value. The default `column_cut` value is set in `xcrud_config.php`. You can increase it there or in your code with `$xcrud->column_cut('column_name', 'value')`.